# access permissions to users in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

How to give different level of permissions to different hierarchies of users?Example:if we want to allow a group of users to access only first 10 hierarchies of the graph and another set of users to access next 10 hierarchies of the graph and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Neo4j itself does not have a user or permission concept.

However you can write your custom [SecurityRules](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html#_server_authorization_rules) as part of a Neo4j Server. A security rule is comparable to a servlet filter that gets wrapped around every request to the server. It can accept or veto a request.